# codeforces problem named Strange List the "MEMORY LIMIT EXCEEDED"

Tags: c++

With reference to the problem named "Strange List" in codeforces following is my code

**But the problem is** All test case is passing but the last test case it is showing"MEMORY EXCEEDED LIMIT" and the last test case value is also huge like for n it is 100000.
Please guide me the way to tackle it

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t; 
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    ll ele,sum=0,i,j,h,n,x;
      
    cin>>n>>x;
    vector <ll> vec;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        cin>>ele;
        vec.push_back(ele);
    }
    for(i=0;i>=0;i++)
    {
         
        if(vec.at(i)%x==1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            h=vec.at(i)/x;
            for(j=0;j<x;j++)
            {
                vec.push_back(h);
            }
            
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    {
     
        sum+=vec.at(i);
    }
   cout<<sum<<"\n";
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use **Dynamic Programming** to solve this problem
>
> Implementation of storing results can be done by using **Vector of pairs**
>
> Below is the **AC code** demonstrates how these kinds of problems can be done efficiently in terms of memory consumption......**Happy Coding :)**

### CODE

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long 

int main(){

    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    
    
    while(t--){
        ll n,x;
        cin>>n>>x;
        
        vector<pair<ll,ll>> a(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>a[i].first;
            a[i].second=a[i].first;  // Storing initial results in second part of pair 
        }
        
        ll s=0;
        ll d=0;
        ll r=0;
        ll k=0;

        while(++r){
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(a[i].first%x==0){
                    s+=a[i].second;
                    a[i].first=a[i].first/x;
                    a[i].second=(a[i].first*pow(x,r));  // updating results 
                }
                else{
                    s+=a[i].second;
                    if(d==0)
                    k=i;
                    d=1;
                }
            }
            if(d)
            break;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        s+=a[i].second;   // getting desired sum 
        
        cout<<s<<"\n";   // printing answer
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @Md Ayyan Fahim ....then why don't you accept my answer please :)

Comment: I am very new here so i dont know actually how to accept the answer

Comment: @MdAyyanFahim Just click on Right tick on my answer near upvote or downvote arrows and it'll be accepted